# Problems with loading image url with Picasso

Tags: android, picasso

I am loading images from a certain url with `Picasso` and I get this error:

> Failed to create image decoder with message 'unimplemented'

This is my adapter class :

```
class CountriesAdapter(var countriesList: ArrayList<Country>) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<CountriesAdapter.CountriesViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): CountriesViewHolder =
        CountriesViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.single_item_country, parent, false))


    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CountriesViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(countriesList[position])
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = countriesList.size


    class CountriesViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        fun bind(country: Country) = with(itemView) {
            itemView.tvCountryName.text = country.name
            Picasso.get().load(country.flagUrl).fit().placeholder(R.drawable.ic_asr_sun).into(itemView.ivCountryFlag)
        }

    }
}
```

I tested the same use case with `Glide` and still doesn't work , so I am assuming I am doing something wrong .

**Edit**
The url is correct

Comment: Check Internet Permission in Manifest

Comment: I do have Internet permission, I am downloading data from internet

Comment: try to log your url? It is getting or not

Comment: yes It is correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this](https://github.com/square/picasso/issues/1587) link here , after I logged the `Picasso` error , which was :

> W/System.err: java.io.IOException: Failed to decode stream.

This issue cannot be resolved here . As the discussion says :

> This error occurs when Android is unable to decode your image. There's
>   nothing Picasso can do to correct this. Consider using another image
>   format or re-encoding your image.